# "pyspark" doesn't work after installing "hadoop" but "spark-shell" still works. Why?

Tags: windows, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I have installed `Spark 3.3.1` and it was running previously with both `spark-shell` and `pyspark` commands. But after I installed `Hadoop 3.3.1` it seems that `pyspark` command doesn't work properly and this is the result of running that:

```
C:\Users\A>pyspark2 --num-executors 4 --executor-memory 1g
[I 2022-11-20 22:36:09.100 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2022-11-20 22:36:09.100 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\share\jupyter\lab
[I 22:36:09.107 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\A
[I 22:36:09.107 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.5.2 is running at:
[I 22:36:09.107 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=0fca9f0378976c7af19886970c9e801ac27a8d1a209528db
[I 22:36:09.108 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=0fca9f0378976c7af19886970c9e801ac27a8d1a209528db
[I 22:36:09.108 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 22:36:09.189 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/A/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8328-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=0fca9f0378976c7af19886970c9e801ac27a8d1a209528db
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=0fca9f0378976c7af19886970c9e801ac27a8d1a209528db
0.01s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

It opens the `Jupyter notebook` but the Spark logo doesn't shown and Python shell wouldn't be available as before in `CMD`. But `spark-shell` still works as below:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://168.150.8.52:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1669062477403).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.15 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.16.1)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 22/11/21 12:28:12 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped


scala>
```

EDIT: These are all my related system variables and paths:

```
JAVA_HOME : C:\ProgramData\OpenJDK
HADOOP_HOME : C:\ProgramData\hadoop
SPARK_HOME : C:\ProgramData\spark
PYSPARK_PYTHON : python
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON : jupyter
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS : notebook
PYTHONPATH : %SPARK_HOME%\python;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip;%PYTHONPATH%
```

system paths:

```
C:\ProgramData\OpenJDK\bin
C:\ProgramData\spark\bin
C:\ProgramData\hadoop\bin
C:\ProgramData\hadoop\sbin
C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: Please share what process you've followed to install things

Answer (score 1):

> It opens the Jupyter notebook but the Spark logo doesn't shown and Python shell wouldn't be available

Jupyter **is** a Python shell (by default).

`pyspark2.cmd` command is just a wrapper around `pyspark.cmd`, by the way. Also, it'll only default to open Jupyter if you set a specific environment variable to do so (`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON`).

The logo isn't necessary to tell you it's working. Try creating a session

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
spark = SparkSession.builder\
  .master("local")\
  .appName("test")\
  .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I tried to run your code but the result is:  `spark = SparkSession.appName("test").getOrCreate()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'SparkSession' has no attribute 'appName'
22/11/25 00:21:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/11/25 00:21:23 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-e888919e-1f50-4dca-b47d-7f7bdb36f953`

Comment: Forgot `.builder`... Updated answer. But still, Spark is "working" because it knows what functions exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Your path has been altered to use sparks python distribution.  You can learn more about this [here](https://realpython.com/add-python-to-path/).

Try:
`echo $PATH`

And look for how many pythons you have.  I bet you have more than 1.

Comment: Note: OP using windows, so `%PATH%`

Comment: Both `echo $PATH` and `echo %PATH` Don't work for me! It only prints out either `$PATH` or `%PATH`.

Comment: About the python, I have these adrresses in my user path:   `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311` and `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts` and `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: See this for how to look at your %PATH% https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows

Comment: @user20551429 The percent sign after the H is necessary